# Enable fields in manage display programmatically D7

Tags: 7, entities

I have just started to use Drupal and I'm trying to add programmatically field in the .install file.

```
 $field = array(
   'field_name' => 'title',
   'cardinality' => 1,
   'type' => 'text',
   'settings'    => array(
     'max_length' => 1024,
   ),
 );

 field_create_field($field);


 $instance = array(
   'field_name'  => 'title',
   'label' => $t('Title'),
   'type' => 'text',
   'widget' => array(
     'type'    => 'text_textfield',
     'weight' => 1.0,
    ),
   'display' => array(
     'default' => array(
       'label' => $t('label'),
       'type' => 'text',
      ),
    ),
 );

$instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
$instance['bundle'] = 'mytype';
field_create_instance($instance);
```

The field is added correctly but it is disabled in the Manage Display. How can I change the region column from 'disabled' to 'content'? I tried to add 'region' => 'content' in the instance array but it is not working and I cannot find a good example or documentation about the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any concrete documentation either. However, I'm going out on a limb here and not 100% certain but, I think you just need to specify a correct formatter and the settings since it works that way in the UI.

```
$instance = array(
   'field_name'  => 'title',
   'label' => $t('Title'),
   'type' => 'text',
   'widget' => array(
     'type'    => 'text_textfield',
     'weight' => 1.0,
    ),
   'display' => array(
     'default' => array(
       'label' => $t('label'),
       'type' => 'text', // <-- invalid formatter
      ),
    ),
 );
```

`text` is not a valid formatter type. It should either be `text_default` or `text_plain` or `text_trimmed` or `text_summary_or_trimmed` or `hidden` (which hides the field from display).